# How to use a function to a ragged dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, function, apply, data-wrangling

I am working with 45 large dataframes of 60 each of extremely, messy timeseries data. But it basically boils down to the two data frames below. I have managed to sort wrangle it down to these two dataframe types, the first is the positions on the y-axis

```
Group1  Group2   Group3            
0         0        0                
1         1        1
3         2        4
5         3        7
          5        8
                   9
```

```
names   samples   t0  XIncrement
Group1    4       0      2   
Group2    5       1      2
Group3    7       2      3
```

I have to create the time for each group. When I write the function for a single group it works great, I get exactly what I want.
1.) t0 is the starting time
2.) xincrement is the time between each sample taken
3.) sample is the number of samples in the set.
4.) Time would be the time for each sample taken

```
    Time_function <- function(samples, t0, XIncrement) {
       
      samples_2 <-c(1:samples)
      Time <- ((samples_2* t0) +XIncrement)
      return(Time)
#}
}
test_function <- Time_function(100, 200e-9, 500e-12)
```

I need it to be "applied" each group. I really am not sure how to either create a new data frame with the information or add it to the rows of the df.
I have tried making an empty data frame and populating it that way and that did not work.

When I transpose the data and get it into list form it, it seems the most usable form but I still cannot get the create Time into the list.

Added For greater clarity: Each Group has it own unique time some groups were sampled more than others.

So, at the end I need to merge Group_1 with Group1_Time, Group_2 with Group2_Time. The data frame will be ragged.

Thanks for any help or guidance you can provide. I have googled and search stackoverflow for information, but I come up empty-handed. If there is a question like this, great, I have yet to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input data shown reproducibly in the Note below, this code combines the list `L` and data frame `DF` and assumes a more appropriate data structure, `ts` class, for the output):

```
make_ts <- function(g, t0, xincr) ts(g, start = t0, deltat = xincr)
tt <- Map(make_ts, L, DF$t0, DF$XIncrement)
tt
```

giving this list of `ts` objects:

```
$Group1
Time Series:
Start = 0 
End = 6 
Frequency = 0.5 
[1] 0 1 3 5

$Group2
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 9 
Frequency = 0.5 
[1] 0 1 2 3 5

$Group3
Time Series:
Start = 2 
End = 17 
Frequency = 0.333333333333333 
[1] 0 1 4 7 8 9
```

Note that we can recover the data, times, start time, deltat and frequency  (= 1/deltat) and convert to a list of data frames like this:

```
lapply(tt, c)
lapply(tt, time)
sapply(tt, start)
sapply(tt, deltat)
sapply(tt, frequency)

library(zoo)
lapply(tt, fortify.zoo)
```

### Note

Since it is not possible to have a data frame with differing column lengths we assume that the first data structure is a list as shown and the second is a data frame.

```
L <- list(Group1 = c(0, 1, 3, 5), Group2 = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5),
  Group3 = c(0, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9))

DF <- structure(list(names = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), samples = c(4L, 
5L, 7L), t0 = 0:2, XIncrement = c(2L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Oh, I did not see that.  THANK!

Comment: Have transferred the command in my comment to the end of the answer.